# How to get a specific item and display the details on another page in an array onclick in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm new to vue and I'm building a client page with an array of client and onclick of a view button the client details show up on another page. I would like to know how to get the specific detail of an item when click and also how it can be viewed on the client details page. I'm unsure how to proceed.
Here is the template section.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class='d-flex justify-center pt-15 '>Clients</h1>

    <div class="mt-15  d-flex justify-space-between ml-10 mr-10">
      <h2 class="font-weight-medium">All Clients</h2>
    <NuxtLink :to="addClient" class="nuxtLink"> <v-btn rounded class='primary button ml-10' style="text-transform:initial; ">
    Add New</v-btn></NuxtLink>
    </div>

    <p class="font-weight-regular" v-if="clients.length === 0">
      You have no clients. Click the add new button to send add a new client.
    </p>


    <div v-else>
<v-simple-table class="ml-10 mr-10 mt-10">
    <template v-slot:default>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left">
            Image
          </th>
          <th class="text-left">
            Name
          </th>
          <th class="text-left">
            Location
          </th>
          <th class="text-left">
            Date
          </th>
          <th class="text-left">
            Action
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr 
          v-for="item in clients" 
          :key="item.name"
        >
        <td>{{ item.image }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
                              <td style="text-decoration: none;" class="td-action">
                                <NuxtLink :to="clientDetail" class="nuxtLink" @click="viewDetail(item)">{{ item.action }}</NuxtLink></td>
        </tr>
       
       <add-client/>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-simple-table>

</div>
</div>


  </div>
</template>
```

And this is the script

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'index',

  data: () => {
    return {
       clientDetail: '/clients/client-detail',
      addClient: '/clients/add-client',
      
      clients:[
      {
            name: 'Cina',
            location: 'Tema',
            date: '13/03/2021',
            action: 'View',
             image: ''
          },
            {
            name: 'Fina',
            location: 'Sakumono',
            date: '12/03/2021',
            action: 'View',
             image: ''
          },
          
          {
            name: 'Mina',
            location: 'Tema',
            date: '13/03/2021',
            action: 'View',
             image: ''
          },
          {
            name: 'Zina',
            location: 'Tema',
            date: '13/03/2021',
            action: 'View',
             image: ''
          },
           {
            name: 'Ama',
            location: 'Tema',
            date: '13/03/2021',
            action: 'View',
             image: ''
          },
          

      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    viewDetail(item){
     item
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have built a few, but my code might be a little hard to follow for someone new to Vue.  I suggest searching the web for Vue CRUD tutorials.  [Here is one](https://bezkoder.com/vue-js-crud-app/) that I found after a quick search.

Comment: Hi thanks...however it has to do with apis. I'll take up your advice and search for some crud tutorials

Comment: However can you show me how to get a specific item using a method?

Comment: See this [vue-client-for-spring-rest](https://github.com/UniquelySimilar/vue-client-for-spring-rest) API client that I wrote.  Specifically look at the [customer views](https://github.com/UniquelySimilar/vue-client-for-spring-rest/tree/master/src/views/customer).  Start with CustomerIndex.vue and search for 'customerDetailOrders', which is part of a router link to the detail page.  Then look at the destination view CustomerDetailOrders.vue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks